# Which points counts in Eps, DBSCAN

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, dbscan

In DBSCAN if we have minPoints=3 and we want to determine if a point is a core point or not, do you count the point itself in the Eps or does it need to have 3 other points in it's Eps?

Answer (score 1):

DBSCAN is an algorithm with a database context.

For a good performance, you need a database that can accelerate such queries using an index - this reduces the runtime from `O(n^2)` to `O(n log n)`.

If you send a range query to a database, it will return *all* the objects within this region, *including* the query point. You would have to manually remove the query point from the results.

But also from a logical point of view: this is a **density measure**. Why would a density estimate have to exclude the query object? It is part of the data set, it should contribute to density like any other object!

I do not see any reason why one should remove the query point from the data set for each query.

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question or confused it with some other question. :)

Comment: No, I havn't. the "point itself" is commonly called the "query point" in a database context. Because you query the database for the neighbors of this point.

Comment: You are most definitely right, I read your post a little to fast. Im sorry, thank you for the replay!

Answer (score 0):

As per the algorithm presented in Wikipedia, the region query for a point `P` returns all the points within `P's` `eps` neighborhood including `P`.

Here's the algorithm (From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN))

```
DBSCAN(D, eps, MinPts)
   C = 0
   for each unvisited point P in dataset D
      mark P as visited
      NeighborPts = regionQuery(P, eps)
      if sizeof(NeighborPts) < MinPts
         mark P as NOISE
      else
         C = next cluster
         expandCluster(P, NeighborPts, C, eps, MinPts)

expandCluster(P, NeighborPts, C, eps, MinPts)
   add P to cluster C
   for each point P' in NeighborPts 
      if P' is not visited
         mark P' as visited
         NeighborPts' = regionQuery(P', eps)
         if sizeof(NeighborPts') >= MinPts
            NeighborPts = NeighborPts joined with NeighborPts'
      if P' is not yet member of any cluster
         add P' to cluster C

regionQuery(P, eps)
   return all points within P's eps-neighborhood (including P)
```

Since core point is defined as one with more points that `MinPts` with the `Eps`, I would say that the point itself is counted while determining whether it's a core point or not.